# How can I delete columns from a table that have mutliple dependencies?

Tags: sql, dependencies

So I have a table that is made up similar to this

```
group_id | code |code_type
 1         45       '9'
 2         56       '0'
 3         56       'NA'
 4         32       'NA'
```

The problem is that I have multiple code_types for the same code, but that's okay, but when there is an 'NA' I want to delete it from the table, because obviously we have another code_type that specifies that code. So we don't need that 'NA'. Hopefully this makes sense, I'll be glad to clarify if needed. So when it's all said and done we will delete row 3 and keep the rest.

Comment: Just a bit of terminology correction:  You're deleting rows, not columns.  If you actually wanted to remove columns from the table, "drop" would be a more appropriate term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a check to Gordon's query to ensure you only delete rows that also have a legit value:

```
delete from <your table>
  where code_type = 'NA'
  and code in (select distinct code from <your_table> where code_type <> 'NA')
```

Comment: Thanks now that I see it I feel silly asking the question, just needed a subquery.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
delete from t
    where code_type = 'NA'
    and exists (
      select null
      from t t1
      where t1.code = t.code
        and t1.code_type <> 'NA'
    )
```

(You can of course replace `delete` with `select *` to see which rows this would delete.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete `'NA'` values, you would simply do:

```
delete from t
    where code = 'NA';
```

Comment: I don't want to delete all 'NA' columns though, just the rows where the code_type can be something else for the same code. So if a code only has one code_type and that's 'NA' then I want to keep it, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You weren't clear whether multiple values other than 'NA' can exist for the same code, however the below CTE makes use of a ROW_NUMBER window function to identify the pattern, then using the DELETE statement outside the CTE to remove any rows that were flagged.

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY group_id) Flag FROM Foo
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE Flag > 1

Comment: Yeah so 'NA' is the only one I want to get rid of, if there are other code_types with the same code it's ok to keep them.